# How to compare json values in swift

Tags: arrays, json, swift

How to compare json array values? Can't understand the logic.

I need to show a price change of cryptocurrencies (increase or decrease) in tableView, while updating data from server https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/

As I understand I have to create two arrays: one for the old values and second for new ones, and function for comparison, where two arrays initially  should be equal. What should I do next? Am I in right direction?

```
var currencies = [Cryptocurrency]()
var newCurrencies = [Cryptocurrency]()
```

I'm getting the array of data through NSNotificationCenter. Should I change something here?

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(getCurrencies), name: Notificator.getCurrencyNotification, object: nil)

@objc func getCurrencies(notification: Notification) {

            if let receivedCurrencies = notification.object as? [Cryptocurrency] {

                self.currencies = receivedCurrencies
                AnimatableReload.reload(tableView: tableView, animationDirection: "up")

                }
            }


func showPriceChanges() {

        currencies = newCurrencies
        ?
    }
```

Comment: Unclear what the issue is, as I see it you need to compare the value of each currency with the old values for the same currency

Comment: Yes. As for now, I can only show these data in tableView (in currencies array) and update them with UIBarButtonItem. I can't understand how to compare price values, if I have only one array (currencies) so far.

Comment: I want to do comparison between two prices like this but  it's wrong :( What do you think? https://imgur.com/a/wycS60w

Comment: I think you need to improve your question instead of posting links to images of code. Add that code to the question instead (as text).